# Error when running bgbuild

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluegiga

I am trying to make a ble host with a BLED112 in the usb of a computer. However, I can't even get it to that step of the work. I am trying to use these steps to make my initial bg Project:
 [Eddystone Beacon](https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-url/implementations/BlueGiga-BLED112)

I am in my windows terminal, in my project folder, and I run the command: `bgbuild [fileName]`

My terminal spits out an error that I can't find on the internet:

```
baudm:216 baude:10 rate:57617
UART boot channel:0
  baudrate   :57600
  actual     :57617
  error%     :0.0295139
  alternate f:1
cdc.xml file read failed
make_xdsc:C:/Bluegiga/ble-1.5.0-137/bin/usbxml.exe error:-1
```

Does anyone know what causes this? It seems like it is an issue with the cdc.xml but honestly, I can't even find a good example of what the cdc is supposed to look like, or how it is supposed to work. Currently mine is just a copy paste of the cdc that is in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

Did you not download the support files for the dongle? In Applications you can find "Bluetooth Smart Software Examples", there is one call USBCDC with a cdc.xml file. This example corresponds to the factory settings for BLED112 dongle.

Comment: Right, that cdc.xml file is identical to the one I am using. How does that relate to my error?

Comment: Do you have the line `<usb_main in="cdc.xml" />` in the project file?

Comment: Yes, I have that line.

Comment: Could you post your files to see if I get the same error?

Comment: I'm dumb. I was missing the last `>` in my cdc.xml. I don't know how I missed it. Thanks for helping. :/

Comment: You're welcome! It would be nice if you upvote my answer/comments :)